# Inkscape: scale and rotate along axis

Tags: inkscape

i want to scale the path uniformly so that nodes 3 and  4 are at 1 and 2. The selected path is a circle and it must remain so. Is there a way to scale along a "custom" axis?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming nodes 1 and 2 are equidistant from nodes 3 and 4 respectively, then yes it's possible.

1. In the snapping controls, enable snapping, snapping to nodes, snapping to paths, and snapping to smooth nodes.
2. Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while you click and drag the corner handle to scale, continue dragging until it snaps into position. These shortcuts used together will ensure scaling proceeds from the object's centre of rotation, and the aspect ratio is constrained.

Example

[image]

Comment: That worked just fine! Thank you very much for your help!